# Is it possible to develop a lockscreen for windows 10 using c#

Tags: c#, lockscreen, windows-10-desktop

Hi i have windows 10 Pro x64 bit and  i will like to know if it's possible to develop a lock screen for windows 10 , without using hacks or not safe methods .. That will close the Pc monitor until a key is pressed . 
I search the google but i did not find anything about that , other than how to disable it or how to change the background image of the already existing one

Comment: why will you want to solve this programming your own application?. Sounds like a simple screensaver to me

Comment: I doubt it is possible. As far as I know, the lock screen is a security feature handled by the OS itself probably in its own desktop so that it is not accessible from regular application code (for ex. by enumerating windows on the screen).

Comment: @NicoRiff there is no way a screensaver ...  since it idont want it to open every 10minutes of inactivity or anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

The authentication experience in Windows is locked-down, for good reason. The system can be extended ([previously using GINA for NT4 through XP, now Winlogon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380543(v=vs.85).aspx)) but only really to allow for new authentication providers, not to change the user-experience.

Of course, you could always build your own full-screen application which mimicks a login screen, and it could be used to invoke the login action and create a session for that user, but if I press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Del</kbd> on my keyboard or <kbd>WinKey+L</kbd>, or choose any of the Logoff options from the start menu then I'll still get the "real" login screen, and that's by-design.

Historical note: Windows XP added the 'Welcome Screen' UX for computers that were not domain-joined. The Welcome Screen UI was a regular userland process which invoked the platform APIs for logging users on and off, and it was loaded into the special local login session. Hypothetically it was possible to replace this screen with another one completely, though I don't believe I ever saw anything beyond a proof-of-concept. There were third-party tools that customized the appearance of the login screen, but they worked by replacing image resources, they didn't actually replace the executable.

...but since Windows Vista the login experience was more controlled and I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) it's all controlled by the core authentication components, so it just isn't possible to replace it - not without seriously modifying the entire Windows security system.

Comment: thanks is it possible to make an autoit script which have access to whatever  key you type , especially the escape .

Comment: @AngaratoSurion No, that would be a **huge** security liability.

Comment: deos the changine of wallpapers turn a monitor  ? i have it on slideshow setting